# When $PA=LU$ should be used?

Tags: numerical-methods, lu-decomposition

I understand that in the case of a matrix when elimination includes a division by $\varepsilon$ one would use partial pivoting to overcome this problem.

Given a matrix, how one can tell whereas $PA=LU$ should be used or just $LU$?

Comment: You should always use $PA=LU$ instead of just $A=LU$.

Comment: @Rahul Is that true even if $A$ is symmetric positive definite?

Comment: @littleO: You're right, SPD matrices do not require pivoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Ask yourself whether you can row reduce
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\\
9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
to reduced echelon form without row exchanging.

Comment: Of course not because of the $0$